# how to chose a choice of a subcommand- dJS v13

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I've been looking for a solution for days and I can't seem to find one. I want to have multiple subcommands (3) and be able to choose an option and then a choice. I know how to respond to an option but I can't seem to respond to a choice after that. Someone, please help me out I would really appreciate it so much! - thank you in advance! (sry if that's confusing)

like this `/find crystal(subcommand) search(option):<choice>` || example: `/find crystal search:random`

i want it to work like his
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jy6Dj.png)

```js
const { Client, MessageEmbed, CommandInteraction } = require("discord.js");

module.exports = {
    name: "find",
    description: "search from crystals to herbs and colors!",
    options: [
        {
            name: "crystal",
            description: "sends a specific or random crystal from datebase",
            type: 1, // 1 is type SUB_COMMAND
            options: [
                {
                    name: "search",
                    description: "specify what crystal you want to search",
                    type: 3, // 3 is type STRING
                    required: true,
                    choices: [
                        {
                            name: "random",
                            value: "crystal_random",
                        },
                        {
                            name: "clearquartz",
                            value: "crystal_clearQuartz",
                        },
                    ]
                },
            ]
        },
        {
            name: "herb",
            description: "sends a specific or random herb from datebase",
            type: 1,
            options: [
                {
                    name: "search",
                    description: "specify what herb you want to search",
                    type: 3,
                    required: true,
                    choices: [
                        {
                            name: "random",
                            value: "herb_Random",
                        },
                        {
                            name: "aloe",
                            value: "herb_aloe",
                        },
                    ]
                },
            ]
        },
        {
            name: "color",
            description: "sends a specific or random color from datebase",
            type: 1,
            options: [
                {
                    name: "search",
                    description: "specify what color you want to search",
                    type: 3,
                    required: true,
                    choices: [
                        {
                            name: "random",
                            value: "color_Random",
                        },
                        {
                            name: "red",
                            value: "color_red",
                        },
                    ]
                },

            ]
        }
    ], 
    /**
     *
     * @param {Client} client
     * @param {CommandInteraction} interaction
     * @param {String[]} args
     */
    run: async (client, interaction, args) => {
        const [ message ] = args;
        const color = '#EEB8B6';

        //--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

        let CrystalsJason = require('../../scripts/crystals.json');    
        let AllCrystals = [ CrystalsJason.crystals.clearQuartz, CrystalsJason.crystals.agate, CrystalsJason.crystals.amethyst, CrystalsJason.crystals.aquamarine, CrystalsJason.crystals.blackTourmaline, CrystalsJason.crystals.carnelian, CrystalsJason.crystals.citrine];

        let crystalOutcome = AllCrystals[Math.floor(Math.random() * AllCrystals.length)];

        const randCrystal = new MessageEmbed()
        .setTitle(`<:crystalmoon:911423663306338355> Crystal: ${crystalOutcome.name} <:crystalmoon:911423663306338355>`)
        .addField(`Properties:  `, `${crystalOutcome.properties}`, true)
        .addField("Fact:  ", `${crystalOutcome.fact}, `, true)
        .setColor(color)
        .setThumbnail(crystalOutcome.image)
        .setFooter(`${crystalOutcome.foot}`)

       if (interaction.options.getSubcommand() === "crystal" ) { 
           const search = interaction.options.getString("search");
           const random = interaction.options.getString("crystal_random").value
           if(search && random){
            return interaction.followUp({embeds: [randCrystal]});
           }
           else {
               return interaction.followUp({content: "didnt work :/"});
           }
        }
        
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its simple. You normally do `interaction.options.getString('search');`

It will give you the value and you don't need to do `.value`. Like for your example where you have chosen `random` it will give `color_Random`. The first name part of the choice is only for the users to see and use.